# How to access MongoDB profile in PHP?

Tags: php, mongodb

I'm trying to access the MongoDB profiler in PHP with the same query I would use in the mongo client:

```
$db = $mongo->selectDB('myapp_db');
$array = $db->execute('return db.system.profile.find();');
echo '<pre>' . print_r($array, true);
```

But I get this:

```
Array
(
    [retval] => Array
        (
            [value] => DBQuery: myapp_db.system.profile -> undefined
        )

    [ok] => 1
)
```

Profiling is enabled and works fine in the client.

Answer (score 1):

Method [MongoDB::setProfilingLevel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.setprofilinglevel.php) — Sets this database's profiling level

```
<?php

$dbname = 'students';
$mongo = (new MongoClient());
$db = $mongo->$dbname;

# 0 (off), 1 (queries > 100ms), and 2 (all queries)
$db->setProfilingLevel(2);

# …
# Some queries 
# …

$response = $db->system->profile->find();
foreach ($response as $query) {
    print_r($query);
}
```

Also:

- Method [MongoDB::getProfilingLevel](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.getprofilinglevel.php) — Gets this database's profiling level
- Method [MongoCursor::explain](http://php.net/manual/en/mongocursor.explain.php) — Return an explanation of the query, often useful for optimization and debugging

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to execute a query in JavaScript, which blocks the server/database, when you can use PHP itself:

```
$mongo = new MongoClient();

// Alternatively, use selectCollection from $mongo->myapp_db
$collection = $mongo->selectCollection('myapp_db', 'system.profile');

foreach ($collection->find() as $document) {
   print_r($document);
}
```

This makes more efficient use of memory, since you can iterate through results instead of fetching the entire [MongoDB::execute()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongodb.execute.php) response in a single array.

Additionally, your original code returns the cursor (a DBQuery object) from JavaScript. To ensure compatibility with other drivers, you should invoke [cursor.toArray()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) before returning. This is discussed in Sammaye's answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15552991/executing-mongodb-find-queries-in-php#comment22045776_15552991).